# Getting the type of a Map's values dynamically

Tags: typescript, types

I have a

```
type MyType1 = Map<string, { prop1: string, prop2: Array<string> }>;
```

and I'd like to create a

```
type MyType2 = { prop1: string, prop2: Array<string> };
```

but dynamically based on `MyType1`.

What I've tried so far:

```
type MyType2 = typeof Array.from((<MyType1>new Map()).values())[0];
```

Very ugly and doesn't work either. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type MyType1 = Map<string, { prop1: string, prop2: Array<string> }>;
type ExtractValue<P> = P extends Map<infer K, infer V> ? V : never;
type MyType2 = ExtractValue<MyType1>;
```

(adapted from [this article](https://itnext.io/typescript-extract-unpack-a-type-from-a-generic-baca7af14e51))

Comment: Just small comment we dont need to infer K as we dont use it, more proper would be - `type ExtractValue<P> = P extends Map<unknown, infer V> ? V : never;`